# Scala enum not seen in another object

Tags: scala

I have the following `enum` in `MyEnum.scala`:

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
  val A, B, C, D, E = Value
}
```

In another object, I am trying to assign an enum to a variable:

```
object SomeOtherObject {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val myValue = MyEnum.A
  }
}
```

However, I am getting:

```
 error: not found: value MyEnum
```

Both of these object are defined in the default package.

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I define everything in the same scala file everything works fine

```
$ cat x.scala
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
  val A, B, C, D, E = Value
}

object SomeOtherObject {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val myValue = MyEnum.A
  }
}

$ scalac x.scala
# no output but produces the .class files
```

If you are defining in 2 different files, try to add a package to the files, and possibly import.

I also tried to define the enum in a `y.scala` file, and the main in the `z.scala` file. It also compiles:

```
$ scalac y.scala z.scala
```